# Bulking/Inserting data from CSV file to CosmosDB via Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I need to upload 400k record as soon as possible to my CosmosDB container. And I come with the question, is there a chance to bulk the file into the container without iterating over the records with Python? I know in C# i can use Bulk executor library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python SDK does not yet support bulk operations. You're only option today is to use .NET or Java SDKs for bulk operations.

Another non-SDK option is to use Azure Data Factory.